# How do you controle zorder across twinx in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, z-order, twinx

I'm trying to control the zorder of different plots across twinx axes. How can I get the blue noisy plots to appear in the background and the orange smoothed plots to appear in the foreground in [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO7DG.png)?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from  scipy.signal import savgol_filter

random = np.random.RandomState(0)
x1 = np.linspace(-10,10,500)**3 + random.normal(0, 100, size=500)
x2 = np.linspace(-10,10,500)**2 + random.normal(0, 100, size=500)

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x1, zorder=0)
ax1.plot(savgol_filter(x1,99,2), zorder=1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x2, zorder=0)
ax2.plot(savgol_filter(x2,99,2), zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340552/matplotlib-two-y-axes-with-mixed-z-order), though not ideal, this is an approach using `twiny` along with `twinx`.

```
# set up plots
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twiny()
ax4 = ax2.twiny()

# background
ax1.plot(x1)
ax2.plot(x2)

# smoothed
ax3.plot(savgol_filter(x1,99,2), c='orange')
ax4.plot(savgol_filter(x2,99,2), c='orange')

# turn off extra ticks and labels
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom=False, top=False)
ax4.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', bottom=False, top=False)
ax3.set_xticklabels([])
ax4.set_xticklabels([])

# fix zorder
ax1.set_zorder(1)
ax2.set_zorder(2)
ax3.set_zorder(3)
ax4.set_zorder(4)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]